# How to check if all elements in an HTMLCollection contain a certain value for a property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, element, htmlcollection

I'm looping over a HTMLCollection like this:

```
elements.forEach((element) => {

  // If all elements in the collection have a "checked" property of "true"
  if (?) { // Not sure what the check should be here, something like `element.checked.every(Boolean)`?
    // Do stuff
  }
});
```

Is it possible to write a check to determine if all the children have an property with the same value? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the NodeList/HTMLCollection to an array, then use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check whether each item in the array matches the condition in the callback:

```js
const res = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].every(e => e.checked)
console.log('All checkboxes checked?', res)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```